# which way of fetching data from Graphql server is better?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I have an application with React as client framework and Graphql for running the API.
Plan is fetching user posts and posts count.

**Client side**

```
const Profile = () => (
 <div>
  <PostCount />
  <Posts />
 </div>  
)

const PostCount = () => ...

const Posts = () => ...
```

We need to display posts in Posts component and the posts count in Count component.
So my question is, which is better.

fetch all of data in Profile component in one request and send it to Post and Count component as props. or fetch posts count in Count component and posts in Post component.

scenario one includes one request to server and bigger chunk of data.

scenario two includes two request to server and smaller chunk of data.

**Scenario one server side:**

```
const schema = `
 type Query {
  feeds(): Feed!
}

type Feed {
 posts: [Post!]!
 count: Int!
}

type Post {
 ...
}
`


async function feed() {
 const posts: await Post.findAll();
 const count = await Post.count();


 return {
  count
  posts,
 }
}
```

**Scenario two server side:**

```
const schema = `
 type Query {
  posts(): [Post!]!
  count(): Int!
 }

 type Post {
  ...
 }
`

async function feed() {
 const posts: await Post.findAll();
 return posts;
}

async function count() {
 const count = await Post.count();
 return count;
}
```

P.S. also consider bigger data. posts and counts are example. for example user posts and user comments.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are correct! it depends on your application to choose a better approach!

`count` is usually faster than fetching data ( someone might mess it up!:D), so if you fetch it separately, you can show it faster while your posts are still in loading.

BTW, GQL handles `Promise` by itself! so there's no need for that async awaits!

Comment: i know both are correct. but which approach has better performance? about the async await. i copied the snippets from my code. the original resolvers have more functions. forget to remove asyinc await.

Comment: calling them separately has better performance, cause you get whichever data is available faster!